# Make a window top priority

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I have a root window with a panel on it. Then there is this function, in which I create a TopLevel (another window) for asking input from user. I'm trying to find some way to make it compulsory for user to either enter input and click OK or cancel to dismiss the window before being able to access the root window. It's like when an error message pops up, you can't just ignore it and do other things in the root window. Does anyone have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm). You can use `widget.wait_window(window)` to achieve this.

Comment: be aware that `wait_window` doesn't restrict events to that window, it simply waits until the window goes away. If you fail to deactivate widgets in the rest of your program, they will remain active.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to apply it. The reason is, the new window is created in a function outside the module which contains the root window. The function is called by a command menu, and it takes the root as a parameter. It's a little bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what is called a `grab`, which forces all events into the window of your choice. There are several methods for managing grab, including [grab_set](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.grab_set-method) and [grab_release](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.grab_release-method).

For an example, see [NiceGrab](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/NiceGrab).

**When working with grabs, exercise extreme care**. It's possible to lock up your computer if you do a global grab and then have a bug that prevents you from releasing it. During development I will often implement a timer that kills the program after a minute or so, so if I lock everything up it will be automatically released after a short wait.